# How would I have GA track an event that happens on another site?

Tags: google-analytics

So I am working with a third party self-contained landing page for a client but I would like any conversions on this site to be tracked to the client's website's google analytics account (or GTM). So, for instance, when the form on the landing page gets submitted, it would fire an event on GA, or when the user downloads a pdf from the success page.

there was a link() function in ga.js, but there doesn't seem to be an equivalent in analytics.js

Just need an example of the code and where on the landing page should it go?

Answer (score 1):

For GTM, use [tracking form submission events](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6106716?hl=en)

On the PDF download event, set up an event tag for when they download the PDF.

Note, if the third-party landing page is on a different domain, you will need to s[etup cross-domain tracking](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034342?hl=en) to ensure your traffic information is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics collects and aggregates data based on tracking ID (some like UA-123123-1). Data collection is realized over the HTTP request to https://www.google-analytics.com/collect endpoint with tracking ID as an URL parameter. There is no built-in limitations for analytics data to be sent from different domains. So you may send a proper request from any 3rd party page or server and this will be tracked within a client's google analytics account. You only need to know client's tracking ID.

Within your page you may just place a common analytics snippet

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=GA_TRACKING_ID"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'GA_TRACKING_ID');
</script>
```

and replace the `GA_TRACKING_ID` with client value. Note that only location.path would be reported in the client's Google Analytics.So if your landing page doesn't have the path part it may be mistakingly reported as the main page `/` of the client's site. To prevent this you may use some arbitrary values to be used in the report and pass them as a parameters with `gtag(...)` call:

```
gtag('config', 'GA_TRACKING_ID', {
  'page_title' : '3rd party landing page', // will be used in reports
  'page_path': '/landingpage' // will be used in reports
});
```